# Repeating twice in sum function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function for total in data but it is repeating the result twice. anyone can help me?

```
function groupBy(arr, key) {
            var newArr = []
                , types = {}
                , newItem, i, j, cur;
            for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
                cur = arr[i];
                if (!(cur[key] in types)) {
                    types[cur[key]] = {
                        type: cur[key]
                        , data: []
                    };
                    newArr.push(types[cur[key]]);
                }
                types[cur[key]].data.push(cur);
            }
            return newArr;
        };
        Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
            var total = 0
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
                total += parseInt(this[i][prop])
            }
            console.log(total);
            return total;
        }
        $scope.totalCreadit = function (st) {
            return st.sum("credits");
        }
```

data

```
 var users = [
            {
               "creditType": "Transfer"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }, {
                "creditType": "Transfer"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }
            , {
                 "creditType": "Bought"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }
            , {
                  "creditType": "Spent"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }
            , {
                 "creditType": "Award"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }
            , {
             "creditType": "Received"
              ,"credits": "50"
            }];
                        $scope.items = groupBy(users, "creditType");
```

It is perfectly displaying the creditType and the total. but when console.log(total) the total is repeating twice. I need to use the total of credits to display chart.

Comment: I dont see any usage or calling the `$scope.totalCreadit()` function. Please provide an jsfiddle for this. Also tag `css` and `wordpress` are too much probably here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/33zydfzd/      this is a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

You have bind `{{totalCreadit(i.data)}}` in the html, so the function is called everytime angular runs a digest cycle, which can happen very often (each event) and angular runs it for each event multiple times, to assure that there are no more changes.

If you not want to watch(two-way-bind) this value and instead do this calculation once, you have to invoke the function in the controller, then save your results into a model variable and bind only your results to the view.

Comment: damn this dude hard